# ELM : Transliterate string

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I'm totally new in ELM. Now i trying to convert some string (that i get from json) to russian translation. For example italy -> Италия.

```
countryConvert : String -> String
countriesTransliterationMap country =
    case country of
        italy -> "Италия"
        canada -> "Канада"
```

But now i receive

```
Any value with this shape will be handled by a previous pattern, so it should be
removed.
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You meant `"italy"` and `"canada"` (with quotes); not `italy` and `canada` (without quotes). Note you'll also need to add `_ -> "default"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code as given does not produce the error you said it does.  However, if I clean it up a bit, it will produce that error:

```
italy : String
italy = "italy"

canada : String
canada = "canada"

countryConvert : String -> String
countryConvert country =
    case country of
        italy -> "Италия"
        canada -> "Канада"
```

To be more precise, it produces that error with Elm `0.18`.  If you try to compile with `0.19`, you'll get a slightly more informative error:

```
$ elm make Countries.elm 
The name `italy` is first defined here:

5| italy = "italy"
   ^^^^^
But then it is defined AGAIN over here:

17|         italy -> "Италия"
            ^^^^^
Think of a more helpful name for one of them and you should be all set!
```

This can still be a bit mysterious though.  The key thing to understand is that `case`  expressions have two purposes, which sometimes overlap: to compare ***individual values*** *or* to ***test structure*** ("shape", in the 0.18 error message's parlance) and "destructure" values -- giving local names to the parts of that structure.  The Elm Guide has a [nice simple example](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/pattern_matching.html).

In order to compare **individual values**, you must have those values **in-line** in each clause of the case expression.  Any variables that you use are assumed to be **new declarations**, local to that clause of the case expression.

So in your case expression, you aren't matching against the values that `italy` and `canada` have across the rest of your program.  Instead, you're declaring two **new local variables** that just happen to *also* be named `italy` and `canada`.  In other words, you haven't "taken apart" the `country` string at all -- all you've done is just declare a new local name for it (`italy`).  And that's why `0.19` is complaining about shadowing.  (See [this explanation](https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/shadowing) for why shadowing is an error rather than just a warning in 0.19.)

Since there is also no **structural** difference between the clauses of the case expression, `0.18` is effectively complaining that your two case clauses are identical.  One will match any string an assign it to a new local variable `italy`; the other will *also* match *any* string, and assign it to a new local variable `canada`.

Alternatives that will work:

You can just inline the values:

```
countryConvert : String -> String
countryConvert country =
    case country of
        "italy" -> "Италия"
        "canada" -> "Канада"
        _ -> country
```

You can use a simple if-else construct:

```
countryConvert : String -> String
countryConvert country =
    if country == italy then
        "Италия"

    else if country == canada then
        "Канада"

    else
        country
```

Or use a `Dict`:

```
countries : Dict String String
countries =
    fromList
        [ ( "italy", "Италия" )
        , ( "canada", "Канада" )
        ]


countryConvert : String -> String
countryConvert country =
    case get country countries of
        Just c ->
            c

        Nothing ->
            country
```

Note that you do still need a `case` expression with this approach.  That's because `Dict.get` might be passed a key that isn't in the Dict.  So you might consider having your function's return type be `Maybe String` as well, so that it's clear that the caller might pass in a country you don't know how to translate.  And that it's the caller's responsibility to decide what to do in that case.

Comment: `case` can be used to also compare individual values, it's not just about comparing structure. Also the code does give the exact error mentioned in 0.19 (after you just change `countriesTransliterationMap` to `countryConvert`).

Comment: I guess the key is you can't compare *top level* values using `case`

Comment: No, that's not right.  @MarkusLaire I tried rephrasing, see if it makes more sense now.